# Determine the support of a gaussian vector

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, support-function

We consider $(X,Y,Z)$ a gaussian with mean $(1,2,1)$ and with covariance matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1\\
-2 & 5 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am asked to determine the support of $(X,Y,Z)$.

The solution says it is $3X + Y − Z = 4$. Where does this come from please?

Answer (score 0):

If $\ W\ $ is a random vector with a multivariate normal distribution, mean $\ \mu\ $ and  covariance matrix $\ \Sigma\ $, then the support of $\ W\ $ is
\begin{align}
\text{supp}(W)&=\mu+\mathcal{N}(\Sigma)^\perp\\
&=\mu+\mathcal{R}(\Sigma)\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \mathcal{N}(\Sigma)\ $ is the nullspace of $\ \Sigma\ $, and $\ \mathcal{R}(\Sigma)\ $ is its range.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it properly eventually:

- Compute Ker(K):

$K \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix} = 0
\Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 \\
-2 & 5 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
      x = -3z \\
      y = -z
    \end{cases}   
$

Therefore, Ker(K) = span$\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

- The image of K is Im(K) = Ker(K)$^{\perp}$ and its equation is:

$3x+y-z+d=0$

- $\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 \\
  2 \\
  1 \\
  \end{pmatrix} \in $ Support($W$) $\Rightarrow d = -4$
- Thus, Support($W$) has equation $\boxed{3x+y-z=4}$